# PHP .htaccess redirect - wrong url is showing

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite my url .
My current is like

```
dura.webeteerprojects.com/products/C-Smart-Smart-Bulbs/
```

I want to change this url to

```
dura.webeteerprojects.com/C-SMART/C-Smart-Smart-Bulbs/
```

Where C-SMART is the category name and C-Smart-Smart-Bulbs is my product name.

What I have tried is,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^C-SMARTproducts/C-Smart-Smart-Bulbs/?$ products/C-Smart-Smart-Bulbs [NC,L]
```

Then I am trying to run `dura.webeteerprojects.com/C-SMART/C-Smart-Smart-Bulbs/` the page will shows the content from `dura.webeteerprojects.com/products/C-Smart-Smart-Bulbs/`

BUT THE URL SHOWING ON THE BROWSER IS `dura.webeteerprojects.com/products/C-Smart-Smart-Bulbs/` 
BUT I HAVE TO SHOW THIS LIKE `dura.webeteerprojects.com/C-SMART/C-Smart-Smart-Bulbs/`

Please help me to solve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(C-SMARTproducts/C-Smart-Smart-Bulbs/)?$ products/C-Smart-Smart-Bulbs/ [NC,L]
```